# API Store 2.0.1 Plugin Issues in GREG 5.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-governance-registry

We recently pushed through the upgrades of our WSO2 instances to IS 5.1, API 1.10.0 and GREG 5.1.  We are a clustered setup, with IS 5.1 serving as Key Manager, API 1.10.0 serving as the API Gateway, and GREG 5.1 serving as the API Store/Publisher, all using the a shared MGT DB.

Once the upgrades completed we started noticing errors such referencing "IAT.CONSUMER_KEY".

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO} -  Failed to get keys for application: 35 {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO}
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'IAT.CONSUMER_KEY' in 'where clause'

Looking into the jar we noticed that the API Store/Publisher jar was still referencing the old column name, CONSUMER_KEY, for IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN.  In a shared setup the IS 5.1 upgrade dropped that column and created the column CONSUMER_KEY_ID.

I installed a vanilla 5.1 Greg and installed the 2.0.1 Store plugin again and the jar impacted definitely appears to be trying to use CONSUMER_KEY:

org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_2.0.1.jar

Anyone hit this issue?  Did we outpace the API Store/Publisher plugin for GREG?  Or, I have just setup the system incorrectly.

Thanks for the help,
Kevin

Answer (score 2):

You need to install API key manager features or use pre-packaged WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 as [[1]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.1.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+1.10.0) when configuring IS 5.1.0 as key manager with APIM 1.10.0.

1. https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.1.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+1.10.0